# How to use requestAnimationFrame to animate multiple squares in a loop

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I am using HTML canvas to draw multiple squares. I have 2 functions: 1) draw a square and 2) draw multiple squares inside a loop.

Now I want to animate these squares using *requestAnimationFrame* to draw these square one at a time. How can I achieve this. Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9c6wt9q/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
       ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function rect(x, y, w, h) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    function drawRect(number, size) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
        rect(i * size, i * size, (i * size) * 2, (i * size) * 2);
      }
    }

    drawRect(10, 5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
var numRects = 10;
var size = 5;
var i = 1;                          // which rectangle we're drawing
var delay = 1000/60;                // num miliseconds between frames
var before = new Date().getTime(),  // last draw time in ms
    now;                            // current time in ms

function animateRect() {
  // get the current time to find if we should draw
  now = new Date().getTime();

  // if sufficient time passed since last draw, draw a rect
  if ( now - before > delay && i <= numRects) {
    rect(i * size, i * size, (i * size) * 2, (i * size) * 2);
    i++;
    before = now;
  }

  requestAnimFrame(animateRect);
}
```

**Edit:**

As Blindman67 pointed out below, `requestAnimFrame` passes the current timestamp since the beginning of the animation to the callback. Here's how to take advantage of it:

```
var numRects = 10;
var size = 5;
var i = 1;                          // which rectangle we're drawing
var delay = 1000/60;                // num miliseconds between frames
var before;                         // last draw time in ms

function animateRect(now) {
    if ( !before ) before = now;
    // if sufficient time passed since last draw, draw a rect   
    if ( now - before > delay && i <= numRects) {
        rect(i * size, i * size, (i * size) * 2, (i * size) * 2);
        i++;
        before = now;
    }

    requestAnimFrame(animateRect);
}
```

However, this would necessitate modifying the shim the OP is using, in order to pass the current timestamp to the callback in `setTimeout`:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function( /* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60, new Date.now());
        };
    })();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: @kayee I just realized I had forgotten to update the `before` draw time on every draw. You'll have to add the `before = now;` line to the body of the condition. See my edit for details.

Comment: I would just like to point out that `requestAnimationFrame` passes the argument `time` to the callback. The time is in milliseconds (same as the Date)  and some browsers even have higher precision with fractions of milliseconds so no need to get the time from the date object.

Comment: @Blindman67 I edited the answer incorporating your feedback. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3):

I provided a frame limiter and tween to show you different ways of animating.  The frame limiter has the steps in your example and the tween has as many steps as it takes to complete in a given amount of time.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//requestAnim shim layer by Paul Irish
//http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function( /* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

function rect(x, y, w, h, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawRect(i, size, color) {
  //for (var i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
  rect(i * size, i * size, (i * size) * 2, (i * size) * 2, color);
  //}
}

var i = 0;
var incr = 1;
var i_max = 10;
var size = 5;
var fps = 10;
var delay = 1000 / fps;
var lastFrame = 0;

var animationTime = 5000
var tweenStep = i_max / ((animationTime/1000) * 60);
var j = 0;

function animateRect() {

  // draw at 60fps
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  drawRect(i, size, "#0000FF");
  
  // This is a frame limiter.
  var currentFrame = Date.now();
  
  if ((currentFrame - lastFrame) >= delay) {
    i += incr;
    if (i >= i_max) i = i_max - 2, incr = -1;
    if (i < 0) i = 1, incr = 1;
    lastFrame = currentFrame;
  }
  
  // this is a tween. The step is calculated for the desired time.
  drawRect(j, size, "#FF0000");
  j += tweenStep;
  if (j >= i_max) tweenStep *= -1,j=i_max-1;
  if (j < 0) tweenStep *= -1, j=0;
  

  requestAnimFrame(animateRect);
  //draw rectangle one by one here...
}

animateRect();
//drawRect(10, 5);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The is perfect.